# Concatenate two tensors in alternate fashion (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

I'd like to concatenate two tensors of `shape=(None, 16)` in alternate fashion (so the result tensor has to be `shape=(None, 32)` where the first array of the first tensor is mixed in alternate fashion with the first one of the second tensor and so on.

How can I do it?

I can't loop on tensors because of unknown `shape[0]`, `zip` function isn't supported for tensors (tensor object is not iterable).
I'm using Tensorflow with Python3.

Comment: what software are you using? You should be much more precise in your questions.

Comment: I wrote It in the title of the question, now I edit and I add that i'm using Python3 with Tensorflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the two tensors have the same shape in the outer (`None`) dimension and you want to alternate between rows of the two tensors, you can do this by adding a dimension with [`tf.expand_dims()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims), concatenating with [`tf.concat()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat), then reshaping with [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape):

```
# Use these tensors as example inputs, but the shape need not be statically known.
x = tf.ones([37, 16])
y = tf.zeros([37, 16])

x_expanded = tf.expand_dims(x, 2)                   # shape: (37, 16, 1)
y_expanded = tf.expand_dims(y, 2)                   # shape: (37, 16, 1)

concatted = tf.concat([x_expanded, y_expanded], 2)  # shape: (37, 16, 2)

result = tf.reshape(concatted, [-1, 32])            # shape: (37, 32)
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I have to do!
If I have two arrays:
x = tf.ones([37, 16])
y = tf.zeros([37, 16])
I want a result array of shape : (37,64)
Where the i array of the first array is mixed in alternate fashion with the i array of the second one.
So, in this example, 37 arrays of length 64 of that kind: [1,0,1,0,1,0,...]

Comment: In that case, where does the 64 come from? (I'd expect concatenating two arrays of shape `(37, 16)` as you describe to yield an array of shape `(37, 32)`.) I updated the answer with a solution for the `(37, 32)` case.

Comment: Yes it was obviously 32, sorry!
Thank you :)

Comment: hey this works like a charm but i don't quite understand why. Is it just an implementation detail one has to know that when you reshape a tensor its elements get ordered in alternating fashion or is there a mathematical meaning to it?